# Dictionary of dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi i am trying to create a dictionary **(socialDict)** inside a dictionary **(dict)** in **ios** at specified location **(ios path)** but it showing error i.e The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

**Code Snippet:**

```
NSArray *arrayDirctories=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES); 
NSString *libraryPath=[arrayDirctories objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *filePath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Hello/breaches.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *socialDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[socialDict setObject:arr forKey:@"count"];
[socialDict setObject:sitesArr forKey:@"sites"];
[socialDict setObject:timeArr forKey:@"time"];
[dict setObject:socialDict forKey:@"social"];
[dict writeToFile:filePath atomically:1];
```

Please can anyone find me way out through this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the content of each array you are setting to the NSDictionary

Comment: 1. arr contains array of integers 2. siteArr contains array os strings  3. timeArr contains array of time string

Comment: please update array elements in your code

Answer (score 1):

but it worked for me..

```
 NSArray*arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
        NSArray*sitesArr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
        NSArray*timeArr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSMutableDictionary *socialDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [socialDict setObject:arr forKey:@"count"];

        [socialDict setObject:sitesArr forKey:@"sites"];
        [socialDict setObject:timeArr forKey:@"time"];
        [dict setObject:socialDict forKey:@"social"];
    //    [dict setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:socialDict];
        [dict writeToFile:filePath atomically:1];
```

the .plist file is

[image]

Comment: Ya its worked, whatever i was saving timeArr it is not in correct format so that error i got. Thanks , thaks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *filePath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.plist"];     
NSArray*arr1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
            NSArray*arr2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
            NSArray*arr3=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

            NSMutableDictionary *mainDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSMutableDictionary *subDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [subDict setObject:arr forKey:@"count"];

            [subDict setObject:sitesArr forKey:@"arr1"];
            [subDict setObject:timeArr forKey:@"arr2"];
            [mainDict setObject:subDict forKey:@"arr3"];
            [mainDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:1];
```

It is working fine